# I want to send a json value as a parameter to php page

Tags: php, json

I create a json value as follows:

```
[ 
 { 
  idx: "261", 
  token: "12931" 
 } 
]
```

I want to send the value in this way.

```
send.php?index={"ids":["261"]}& token={"ids":["12931"]}
```

I do not know what to do to put a parameter in the page that way.

Comment: If json consists of two keys only, why do not you send them as variables? `send.php?ids=261&token=12931`

Comment: zkanoca//
Unfortunately, the server handles developer has put me up to receive value from json

Comment: I have to send that value to send.php, to try to handle post.

Comment: in ajax you could do like :
`$.ajax(
{  
type: "POST", 
 url: "send.php",  
data: { index: {"ids":["261"]}, token:{"ids":["12931"]} }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
console.log(msg );
});
`